# Firebase cloud function that writes to database writes multiple times and never returns

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a cloud function to write to a firebase db. It's supposed to be really simple. I want to write and return a 200. The example they give does a redirect in the then callback, but I don't want to redirect. Unfortunately, my function hangs indefinitely and writes the same message to the db 3,4,5,6 times.

I'm pretty sure I am doing the return incorrectly. I tried to return res.status = 200 from the then callback, but that didn't work either.

This is what I have currently:

```
exports.createEvent = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const name = req.query.name;
    const description = req.query.description;
    const location = req.query.location; //json? lat/lng, public,
    const date = req.query.date;

    // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    return admin.database().ref('/Event')
        .push({name : name, description : description, location : location, date : date});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you watch the official Video Series on Cloud Functions (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) and in particular the first video on Promises titled "Learn JavaScript Promises (Pt.1) with HTTP Triggers in Cloud Functions".

You will see that for an HTTTS Cloud Function you **have to** send a response to the client (watch the video at 8:50).

Therefore the following modifications to your code should do the trick:

```
exports.createEvent = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const name = req.query.name;
    const description = req.query.description;
    const location = req.query.location; //json? lat/lng, public,
    const date = req.query.date;

    // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    admin.database().ref('/Event')
        .push({name : name, description : description, location : location, date : date})
        .then(ref => {
           res.send('success');
        })
        .catch(error => {
           res.status(500).send(error);
        })
});
```